# podman montar imagen de miktex para generar pdf

Tags: windows10, latex, podman

estoy tratando de correr un contenedor con miktex en windows.

La imagen la baje mediante el comando

```
podman pull docker.io/library/miktex/miktex
```

Cree la carpeta y le puse los archivos que quisiera usar para generar el pdf en la ruta `C:\miktex\work`

[image: imagen de la carpeta]

cuando trato de correr

```
run --rm -ti -v C:/miktex:/miktex/.miktex -v $(pwd):/miktex/work -e MIKTEX_GID=$(id -g) -e MIKTEX_UID=$(id -u) miktex/miktex pdflatex cv_2.tex
```

obtengo el error

> Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'g' in -g)

Ese comando lo intente tomar de https://hub.docker.com/r/miktex/miktex

Trate de entender que estaba pasando mendiante [esta pagina](https://www.tutorialworks.com/podman-rootless-volumes/) pero quede chino.

Como podria montar el volumen para generar con pdflatex el archivo pdf en la carpeta `C:\miktex\work`?

Answer (score 0):

Si uno hace `man id` en *nix, el man dice

> id - print real and effective user and group IDs

Así pues, lo que hay que buscar es cómo darle los datos del usuario que lo corre (y su grupo o equivalente) al arranque.

No sé si en tu entorno puedas probar la opción [`--uidmap`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#uidmap-container-uid-from-uid-amount) con algo como `--uidmap $uid:0:1`. O de pronto jugando con `--userns`, no lo sé con certeza. Mi kungfú en podman es bajo.

En los docker compose uno usa `${UID}`, `${GID}`. No sé si sirva.